# VBA IF SUM Function

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, sum

I am trying to write vba code that completes this task on a range of cells with values:
`=IF(SUM(A2:B2)>0,"Yes","No")`

but cannot get it to operate correctly. Here's what I have so far. Sorry I'm new to vba.

```
Sub formula3()

    'formula3

    On Error Resume Next
    On Error GoTo 123:

    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastrow As Integer
    Dim wsClient As Worksheet
    Set wsClient = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("All P&C Client Data")
    lastrow = wsClient.Cells.Find("*", wsClient.Range("F1"), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).row

    For i = 2 To lastrow

        Sheet3.Range("t2").value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheet3.Cells(i, 1), Sheet3.Cells(i, 2))

    Next

    123:

    value = "0"
    Resume Next


    lastrow = wsClient.Cells.Find("*", wsClient.Range("F1"), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).row
    For i = 2 To lastrow


        If Sheet3.Cells(i, 20) > 0 Then
            wsClient.Cells(i, 19) = "Yes"
        Else
            wsClient.Cells(i, 19) = "No"
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: This code is a bit all over the place. Do you also have some sample data, with desired output? To make more clear what your are after. Also, if the above code doesn't work for you, can you specify which part of it does not do what you intended it to do/errors out?

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but you might be after something like the below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub formula3() ' Procedure needs a better name.
    Dim clientSheet As Worksheet
    Set clientSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("All P&C Client Data")

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = clientSheet.Cells(clientSheet.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim rowIndex As Long
    For rowIndex = 2 To lastRow ' Skip header row.
        Dim total As Variant ' Could declare as Double, but values read from a worksheet can be non-numeric (errors, text, etc.)
        total = Application.Sum(clientSheet.Range("A" & rowIndex, "B" & rowIndex))

        Debug.Assert IsNumeric(total)

        clientSheet.Cells(rowIndex, "T").Value = IIf(total > 0, "Yes", "No")
    Next rowIndex
End Sub
```

- I recommend always putting `Option Explicit` at the top of every module you have code in. It helps identify simple errors like typos by forcing you to declare every variable you use.
- You can specify a column letter to `Cells`. I find `Cells(i, "T")` to be easier to follow than `Cells(i, 19)`.
- I've assumed `Sheet3` and `clientSheet` refer to the same worksheet (since the last row was determined using the `"All P&C Client Data"` worksheet). On this basis, I've removed `Sheet3` from the code.
- This code currently loops and reads/writes one row at a time. Generally you don't want to do this (it's slow), but if you're new/still learning, this approach might be easier to understand (for now).